# Problem in saving the edited information in the table in ASP.NET with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have designed a web form in ASP.NET using First Code, I have added a table for the user profile to the default database with the migration method. I have no problem creating a user and calling the user, but it is not saved in the table to edit the user's profile.
I have tried most of the methods suggested on this site but have not succeeded
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Framework 6.4.4
My pages are as follows:

The Context and Table page:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext()
        :base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfiles> userProfiles { get; set; }
}
public class UserProfiles
{
    [Key]
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Father { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PhonNumber { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

and Migration Page is:

```
public partial class UserProfiles : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserProfiles",
            c => new
                {
                    userId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                    Father = c.String(),
                    PersonId = c.String(),
                    PhonNumber = c.String(),
                    BirthDate = c.String(),
                    Address = c.String(),
                    StatusId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.userId);
        
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.UserProfiles");
    }
}
```

And Update Button code is:

```
protected void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentId = User.Identity.GetUserId();


        UserProfiles profiles;

        using(UserContext context = new UserContext())
        {
            profiles = context.userProfiles.Where(c => c.userId == currentId).First();
        }

        profiles.Father = father.Text;
        profiles.PersonId = personId.Text;
        profiles.BirthDate = birthDate.Text;
        profiles.PhonNumber = mobilNumber.Text;
        profiles.Address = Address.Text;
        profiles.StatusId = Convert.ToInt32(statusId.Text);

        using(UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            db.Entry(profiles).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: That's not how EF is used. A DbContext is a unit of work, not a database connection or database model. It doesn't even open a connection unless it has to read data or persist changes. It tracks all changes and persists all of them in a single internal transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. In your code you're using two DbContexts instead of one, which means the second context has no idea where the data came from. Use only the first DbContext, simply update the properties you want and call SaveChanges just before exiting the `using` block. There's no need for `db.Entry(..)`.

Comment: The [Multiple operation documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic#multiple-operations-in-a-single-savechanges) shows you can perform multiple operations inside a single context block and all the changes will be persisted in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called

Comment: Thank you for your guidance
I used a DB context in the same way before, but I still didn't get any results.
I used the commands 'where', 'findbyId', 'FirstorDefault', and 'SingleOrDefault' to find the line, but there was no result. When running the program, all the commands are executed correctly and there are no errors, but the changes are not recorded in the table.

Comment: I also used the following methods but did not get an answer

Comment: 'using(var _db = new UserContext()) { var res = _db.mytable.where(x => x.id == Id).FirstOrDefault(); res.name = name; //and mor _db.savechange(); //and in other await _db.savechangeasynce();}'

Comment: But it was useless